# Sending pictures of a network with Android

Tags: java, android, image, network-programming

I was just wondering which file format is best to use for sending over a network, JPEG or PNG? I need it to be as fast a possible as it is being compressed and sent from an Android phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine for sending images over the network but:

.JPEG will typically be smaller in size, but depending on how compressed it is (since jpeg is a lossy format) you may not have good enough detail.

.PNG with typicaly be larger in size compared to JPEG but it is a lossless compression format which mean it'll compress the file (depending on the image) and will keep quality.

One more thing:

When storing images that contain text, line art, or graphics – images with sharp transitions and large areas of solid color – the PNG format can compress image data more than JPEG can, and without the noticeable visual artifacts which JPEG produces around high-contrast areas.